# Converting string of Integers to bytearray for pyserial

Tags: arrays, pyserial, python-3.7

I'm trying to convert a string from a file into a byte array to send over pyserial in python 3
I have a string like:

> [66, 1, 32, 1, 3, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 4, 102, 198]

which I need to send over the line as:

> \x42\x01\x20\x01\x03\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x01\x04\x66\xc6

I've tried many things without much success.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `bytes([66, 1, 32, 1, 3, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 4, 102, 198])`

Comment: that outputs b'B\x01 \x01\x03\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x04\x02\xe5\x94'  I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not outputting whats expected.

Comment: even.  `'bdata=b'\x42\x01\x20\x01\x03\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x04\x02\xE5\x94'  
print(bdata)'`  prints                 `b'B\x01 \x01\x03\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x04\x02\xe5\x94'`    why is it being changed?

Answer (score 0):

You might do

```
data = [66, 1, 32, 1, 3, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 4, 102, 198]
 
a = bytearray()
for item in data:
  a.append(item)

byte_str = bytes(a)
```

Output:

b'B\x01 \x01\x03\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x01\x04f\xc6'